# Graph DB Friends, Likes, Events

Tags: graph, neo4j

I'm working on a social networking site and am very new to graph databases.  I understand how to implement a graph db with only friends.  However, where do objects such as 'Likes' and 'Events' fit in on the graph, or do they fit in at all?  I want to be able to query for not only friends, but sort events based on friends' likes and so on.

Answer (score 1):

for some modeling examples in Neo4j, have a look at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/cypher-cookbook-path-tree.html for a time-indexing structure that can be combined with custom categories on the events, and more generally, the domain modeling examples at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/data-modeling-examples.html .

Also, regarding event streams, there has been some great research by Rene Pickhardt with Graphity, http://www.rene-pickhardt.de/graphity-an-efficient-graph-model-for-retrieving-the-top-k-news-feeds-for-users-in-social-networks/

Comment: Cannot find 3 documents.